# Is it possible to add process for custom entities in managed solution in Dynamics crm?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a managed solution where I want to add a process/workflow with custom entities. I am able to add process in unmanaged solution for custom entities but have any way to do in managed solution or any alternative way to do so?

Please suggest me what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Managed solution is not recommended for regular development lifecycle projects, as the future schema changes will be challenging. Managed solutions are good for redistributable components like CRM REST Builder, where author want to have full control & customizations are not allowed in those components as that may break future upgrades of that particular managed solution.

Still you can go ahead & create a standalone solution with your custom entities, then add a WF for that entity. Finally you can export as managed solution to import in other environments (usually only Prod). This way you can customize anytime in lower region like Dev/QA, but Prod can have managed solution & if anything goes wrong - deleting managed solution in Prod will wipe out components + data. You can change in Dev again & a fresh exported Managed solution can be imported in Prod.

Managed solution components cannot be directly customized.

Comment: This argument is always in hot debate among MVPs and experienced professionals, but Matt Barber would say that unmanaged solutions should only be used in Dev, and managed in all other environments (QA/Stage/Prod)

Comment: @Daryl Great, this becomes quite challenging nowadays when Devops process is forced & continuous dev + deploy is part of daily customizations - the schema changes are so crucial. We cannot give a blanket statement to the community without analyzing case by case CRM implementations.

Comment: Agreed, I'm in the unmanaged camp myself for a majority of use cases, but I would recommend your QA being as close as possible to Prod